# Functional Programming - then() between chained filter/map calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, functional-programming, method-chaining

I am parsing data like this:

```
getData()
.filter(fn)
.filter(fn2)
.filter(fn3)
.map(fn4)
```

in which the filters are conceptually separated and do different operations.

For debugging purposes, is there a JavaScript library or a way to wrap promises such that I can do this:

```
getData()
.filter(fn)
.then((result) => { log(result.count); return result })
.filter(fn2)
.then(debugFn)    // extra chained debug step (not iterating through arr)
.filter(fn3)
.map(fn4)
```

Or is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: How about `.forEach()`? oh wait no, it returns `undefined`

Comment: `.forEach` doesn't return the original array, so that wouldn't work

Comment: well you could use `.map()` and just return each value unmodified.

Comment: also, I don't want to use `forEach` or `map` because they will iterate through array unnecessarily.

Comment: Well if you want to include it in the chain like that you have to face the fact that each `.filter()` returns an array. You're limited in what you can do to the functions on `Array.prototype`.

Comment: "Is this an anti-pattern" - depends how high up the ivory tower you want to go. This is a "side effect" and as such is not considered "pure", but, it also seems a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do. I am pretty sure you could just write an extension (via JS prototype mechanism) on promise that lets you perform some higher order function (in your case logging the current state of the iterated collection) before returning the source (like the monkey-patch example below).

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing more about `debugFn()`. for example, is it synchronous or asychronous? Does it accept a single value or an array of values?

Comment: Why would you introduce Promises and `.then()` just for debugging a funamentally synchronous process (if that's what it is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

*After some thoughts I'm convinced that the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395969/1244884) to this question has been given by V-for-Vaggelis: just use breakpoints.*

*If you do proper function composition then inserting a few `tap` calls in your pipeline is cheap, easy and non intrusive but it won't give you as much information than what a breakpoint (and knowing how to use a debugger to step through your code) would.*

---

Applying a function on `x` and returning `x` as is, no matter what, already has a name: `tap`. In libraries like [ramda.js](/questions/tagged/ramda.js), it is described as follow:

> Runs the given function with the supplied object, then returns the object.

Since `filter`, `map`, ... all return new instances, you probably have no other choice than extending the prototype.

We can find ways to do it in a *controlled* manner though. This is what I'd suggest:

```js
const debug = (xs) => {
  Array.prototype.tap = function (fn) {
    fn(this);
    return this;
  };
  
  Array.prototype.debugEnd = function () {
    delete Array.prototype.tap;
    delete Array.prototype.debugEnd;
    return this;
  };
 
  return xs;
};

const a = [1, 2, 3];

const b =
  debug(a)
    .tap(x => console.log('Step 1', x))
    .filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
    .tap(x => console.log('Step 2', x))
    .map(x => x * 10)
    .tap(x => console.log('Step 3', x))
    .debugEnd();

console.log(b);

try {
  b.tap(x => console.log('WAT?!'));
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Array prototype is "clean"');
}
```

If you can afford a library like Ramda, the safest way (IMHO) would be to introduce `tap` in your pipeline.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];

const transform =
  pipe(
      tap(x => console.log('Step 1', x))
    , filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
    , tap(x => console.log('Step 2', x))
    , map(x => x * 10)
    , tap(x => console.log('Step 2', x))
  );
  
console.log(transform(a));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, filter, map, tap} = R;</script>
```

Comment: Using breakpoints wouldn't help in all cases—let's say I wanted to send a webhook between different steps

Comment: @aks It should be possible though. When a breakpoint is active, the debugger still allows you to inspect, interact and run new code.

Answer (score 2):

You could monkey-patch `Array.prototype`, but it's **not recommended**.

As long as *you only use it for debugging*:

```
Array.prototype.debug = function (fn) {
    fn(this);
    return this;
};

// example usage
[1, 2, 3].map(n = > n * 2).debug(console.log).map(n => n * 3);
```

It's not a promise - you probably don't need async - but gives you `.then`-like behaviour.

Comment: Is there a "safer" way to do this—like create an `ThenableArray` that extends an `Array`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding functions to built-in object prototypes is controversial, so many people might advise against it. However, if you *really* want to be able to do what you're asking, that's probably the only option:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "examine", {
  value: function(callback) {
    callback.call(this, this);
    return this;
  }
});
```

Then you can put `.examine(debugFn)` calls in the chain of `.filter()` calls, as you described.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that you're trying to use the chaining pattern that doesn't scale very well.

`a.method().method()` does only let you apply functions (methods) that are supported by the prototype of the given context (`a` in this case).

I'd rather suggest you to take a look at function composition (`pipe` VS `compose`). This design pattern doesn't depend on a specific context, hence you can provide behaviour externally.

```js
const asyncPipe = R.pipeWith(R.then);

const fetchWarriors = (length) => Promise.resolve(
  Array.from({ length }, (_, n) => n),
);

const battle = asyncPipe([
  fetchWarriors,
  R.filter(n => n % 2 === 0),
  R.filter(n => n / 5 < 30),
  R.map(n => n ** n),
  R.take(4),
  R.tap(list => console.log('survivors are', list)),
]);

/* const survivors = await */ battle(100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

As you can see from the snippet above, it is not really needed for the `Array` type to implement everything...

Answer (score 1):

I believe one could use breakpoints to debug something like this.

Answer (score 1):

When you dont want to overwrite the prototype of either you could write a wrapper function that takes a promise and gives you a modified promise that has the additional features you want. However the problem here is that you will need to import all methods that *may* be used, which is bad for tree-shaking.

The [ES6 pipeline operator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) tries to address this problem.

Until then things like lodashs `_.flow` remain, that allow you to do this:

```
_.pipe([
  _.filter(fn),
  _.filter(fn2),
])(data);
```

Now you basically want this in an async way. This should be pretty easy to accomplish with tools like Ramda.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want pretty easily with [rubico](https://github.com/richytong/rubico), a functional (programming) promise library

```js
import { pipe, tap, map, filter, transform } from 'rubico'

const pipeline = pipe([
  getData,
  filter(fn),
  tap((result) => { log(result.count) }),
  filter(fn2),
  debugFn,
  filter(fn3),
  map(fn4),
])
```

you can use the above pipeline as a transducer (without debugFn for now, since I am not sure the exact nature of what it does) using rubico's `transform`

```js
transform(pipeline, [])
```

you are left with an efficient transformation pipeline based off transduction.